# Hyperledger besu onchain permissioning error

Tags: besu, hyperledger, permissioned-chain

i'm following a tutorial on how to create an onchain permissioning network with hyperledger besu : https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Tutorials/Permissioning/Getting-Started-Onchain-Permissioning/
but i'm facing the current error:

```
    node-1  | ANTLR Tool version 4.7.1 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.9.2
node-1  | ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.1 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.9.2
node-1  | ANTLR Tool version 4.7.1 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.9.2
node-1  | ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.1 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.9.2
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:51:59.107+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Using LibEthPairings native alt bn128
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:51:59.124+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Using the native implementation of the signature algorithm
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:51:59.144+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Starting Besu version: besu/v22.1.2/linux-x86_64/openjdk-java-11
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.068+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Static Nodes file = /opt/besu/usr/app/data/static-nodes.json
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.071+00:00 | main | INFO  | StaticNodesParser | StaticNodes file /opt/besu/usr/app/data/static-nodes.json does not exist, no static connections will be created.
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.071+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Connecting to 0 static nodes.
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.079+00:00 | main | INFO  | Besu | Security Module: localfile
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.110+00:00 | main | INFO  | DatabaseMetadata | Lookup database metadata file in data directory: /opt/besu/usr/app/data
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.221+00:00 | main | INFO  | RocksDBKeyValueStorageFactory | Existing database detected at /opt/besu/usr/app/data. Version 1
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:00.891+00:00 | main | INFO  | KeyPairUtil | Loaded public key 0xf0d75da70ed29306e0e4ce8cd22a34a607591e68d07b7a33932cf8ca34895c8a8745a1784dba0c3b0fff8bb4b6541f8cfebf0bc8d2a36755e8e7eabdd0c64916 from /opt/besu/usr/app/data/key
node-1  | 2022-07-28 14:52:01.211+00:00 | main | INFO  | ProtocolScheduleBuilder | Protocol schedule created with milestones: [London: 0]
node-1  | Error: node permissioning contract at address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000009999 does not match the expected interface version 2.
node-1  |
node-1  | To display full help:
node-1  | besu [COMMAND] --help
node-1 exited with code 1
```

my config.toml file is the following:

```
# Valid TOML config file
data-path="usr/app/data" # Path

# Network

rpc-http-enabled=true
rpc-http-api=["ADMIN","ETH","NET","PERM","QBFT"]
host-allowlist=["*"]
rpc-http-cors-origins=["all"]

# Chain
genesis-file="/usr/app/genesis.json" # Path to the custom genesis file

permissions-accounts-contract-enabled=true
permissions-accounts-contract-address="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000008888" 
permissions-nodes-contract-enabled=true
permissions-nodes-contract-version=2
permissions-nodes-contract-address="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000009999"

min-gas-price=0
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I didn't find any contract ending by ```0x000..99999``` in the ```v2.1.6```.
Did you mean ```0x000..9999```?
If yes; what makes the difference between your issue and your solution? Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using the latest contract `0x000..99999` from the genesis file in the last release here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/permissioning-smart-contracts/releases/tag/v2.1.6